# Angular passing data from parent to child is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use component interaction to pass data from parent to child

In parent component:

```
<app-news [leonardType]="countTitle"></app-news>
```

Child component

```
export class NewsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

  @Input() leonardType: string;
  title;
  constructor(
    public newsService: NewsService
  ) {}
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log(this.leonardType); ==> undefined
    console.log(this.newsService.leonardCategory[this.leonardType]); ==> undefined
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = this.newsService.leonardCategory[this.leonardType];
    console.log(this.leonardType); ==> undefined
    console.log(this.newsService.leonardCategory[this.leonardType]); ==> undefined
}
```

In child component service I have an object:

```
leonardCategory = {
  countTitle: "TITLE 1",
  indTitle: "TITLE 2"
};
```

I think that the view is not yet rendered but either in `ngAfterViewChecked` I get undefined output of `leonardType`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass `countTitle` text, just wrap it into `''`. Without `''` it is considered as a property in the component which is `undefined`, so why you get `undefined` in the child component.

```
<app-news [leonardType]="'countTitle'"></app-news>
```

or just without `[]`

```
<app-news leonardType="countTitle"></app-news>
```

Comment: The input type is string. @Input() leonardType: string;

Comment: What I would pass is only text, is it possible ?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan **leonardType** is **string** :|

Comment: @infodev Sorry. You need to pass text `countTitle` to the child, so include it in the `''`. Updated

Answer (score 0):

use  `*ngIf="isLoading$ | async"` in parent component to check whether data from backend is still loading or loading completed, once data loaded completely in parent component, the data will be passed to child component